# Failed to get datakey value on ItemDataBound

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I searched the web and  found the example, but I still get it right. I have a multiple datakey on datagrid and I get index out of range error. Would someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

There is my aspx

```
<asp:datagrid id="dgrTrans" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="False" gridlines="Both" borderstyle="NotSet" cssclass="dgrd w97p" cellpadding="2" 
                                  horizontalalign="center" datakeyNames="ID, Description" >
```

There is my code to retrieve the value on ItemDataBound

```
Select Case e.Item.ItemType
            Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem, ListItemType.EditItem

                Dim currentItem As DataGridItem = CType(e.Item, DataGridItem)
                Dim dKey As DataKey = Me.dgrTranscripts.DataKeys(currentItem.ItemIndex)
                Dim cn As String = dKey("Description").ToString()
  end select
```

I also tried the following code, but I get the "Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid." error

```
Dim cn As String = dgrTranscripts.DataKeys(e.Item.DataItem("Description)).ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

The index in your case can only be 0 or 1 because there are only two of the keys. You are trying to retreive DataKey with index that equals to currentitem.ItemIndex, which can be as big as many items you have, therefore you are getting an out of range error. You need to use either 0 or 1 as a DataKey index. I cannot give you a definitive answer because you did not specify what exactly you are trying to do...

EDIT:

Instead of `ItemDataBound`, use `DataBound` event and loop through every row to get its value.
Here is an example with `GridView`

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBound
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim cn = GridView1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

On `ItemDataBound`, DataGrid does not know that there are keys yet. They will be assigned on `DataBound`

Comment: I want assign the valeu fo datakey ID to the string. I still have a problem. Do you help me again

Comment: I checked the datakey collocetion by using dgrTranscripts.DataKeys.count and it is 0. I am totally confused now. What's wrong on my code

Comment: At what point in the lifecycle have you checked the count? Also, where are you trying to retrieve the values? Could you post more code? Try in the `DataBound` event

Comment: I checked it on ItemDataBound